# Performance impact of ngDoCheck, ngAfterViewChekedd and other alike angular lifehooks

Tags: javascript, angular

What is the impact of the following two methods (and if others alike) on angular application's performance?

ngDoCheck

ngAfterViewChecked

As when implemented this two methods they keep on firing (continuously), and when used what one should take care of?